# How does one evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+1)\sin(x-1)}{x^2-1}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I understand that we have poles at $1$ and $-1$, so I was trying to just dimple out at those points, using a semi-circle contour. However, I keep getting stuck at those dimples - it seems to me that when using $\pm 1 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}$, the integral vanishes at those dimples, which I believe shouldn't happen. I know the answer should be $\frac{\pi}{2}\sin 2$, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Those are not poles. They are removable singularities.

Comment: If $f(x)=\sin(x)/x,$ then the integrand is $f(x-1)f(x+1),$ and $f$ has no pole, just a removable singularity.

Comment: Using the fact that the integrand is even, this can be solved surprisingly easily with Plancherel's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't actually any poles at $x = \pm 1$ - indeed, $\frac{\sin(z)}{z} \to 1$ as $z \to 0$ and is bounded in particular.

The important thing to note is that the current function you've got isn't great for contour integrals. Indeed, $|\mathrm{sin}(z)|$ grows very (exponentially) quickly as $|\mathrm{Im}(z)| \to \infty$, so you'll want to replace it by something else. I suggest using the fact

$$\sin(a)\sin(b) = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b)\Big)$$ and viewing $\cos x$ as the real part of $\exp (ix)$. Then it becomes a standard integral. If you need any additional help, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

We first split the integral into two integrals using product-to-sum formula and find the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x+1) \sin (x-1)}{x^2-1} d x=&\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2-\cos (2 x)}{x^2-1} \\
= & \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2-\cos (2 x)}{x^2-1} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2}{x^2-1} d x-\frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2 x)}{x^2-1} d x\\=& -\frac{1}{4} \int_ {-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2 x)}{x^2-1} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Resolving the integrand into partial fractions yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & -\frac{1}{8} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\cos 2 x}{x-1}-\frac{\cos 2 x}{x+1}\right) d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{8}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2(1+x))}{x} d x-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2(x-1))}{x} d x\right] \\
= & -\frac{1}{8}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 \cos (2 x)-\sin 2 \sin (2 x)}{x} d x-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 x \cos 2+\sin 2 \sin 2 x}{x} d x\right] \\
= & \frac{\sin 2}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2 x}{x} d x\\=&\frac{\pi \sin 2}{4} 
\end{aligned}
$$